# Sort a list of reversed objects

Tags: python, sorting, python-2.x

I was looking for a way to do a reverse-[lexicographical](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lexicographical_order) sort without using a lameda function, and noticed something odd when using `reversed`:

```
>>> tuples = [
...    (1, 2, 3),
...    (2, 3, 1),
...    (3, 1, 2),
... ]
>>> sorted(tuples, key=reversed)
[(3, 1, 2), (2, 3, 1), (1, 2, 3)]  # wrong
>>> sorted(tuples, key=reversed)
[(2, 3, 1), (1, 2, 3), (3, 1, 2)]  # also wrong
>>> sorted(tuples, key=reversed)
[(2, 3, 1), (3, 1, 2), (1, 2, 3)]  # heyyy, third time lucky!
```

How does python sort a list of `reversed` instances?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's ordering by memory location of the `reversed` objects:

```
>>> x = reversed((1,2))
>>> y = reversed((2,1))
>>> sorted([x,y])
[<reversed at 0x7fffe84045d0>, <reversed at 0x7fffe84eb210>]
>>> sorted([y,x])
[<reversed at 0x7fffe84045d0>, <reversed at 0x7fffe84eb210>]
```

Result can change on subsequent runs, because new `reversed` objects are allocated each time.

However, it's a [CPython implementation detail](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#comparisons) and not guaranteed in the language reference.